# How to calculate the schema size in oracle db in sql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, size, schema

There is task given by my team to compare the schema size of prod and dev so how can you calculate the schema size.

Answer (score 0):

select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 "GB" from dba_segments where owner='SCHEMA_NAME';